# Wait for elevation service request callback

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to build a little app with the Google Map API, and since it's my first javascript app (I already know about the language, but I almost never use it), I'm struggling with a little problem.

I'm trying to get the elevation related to a marker, using the ElevationService, in order to push the two datas ({marker, elevation}) into an array. However, the line where I push the datas into the array is hit before the callback function for `getElevationForLocations` has been called, resulting in the push of an undefined data (elevation).

I think I should use an asynchronous function in order to wait for the callback to be executed before the data has been pushed, but I don't know how to use it.

Could anyone give me indications on that ?

Thanks a lot,
Méta

P.S.: Here is my script

```
    var markers = [];

    function initMap()
    {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 4,
            center: {lat: -25.363882, lng: 131.044922 },
            mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });

        var elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService;

        map.addListener('click', function(e) {
            addMarker(e.latLng, map, elevator);
        });
    }

    function getElevation(location, elevator) {
        var elevation;
        // Initiate the location request
        elevator.getElevationForLocations({
            'locations': [location]
        }, function(results, status)
        {
            if (status === 'OK') {
            // Retrieve the first result
                if (results[0]) {
                    return results[0].elevation;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function placeMarkerAndPanTo(latLng, map) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map
        });
        map.panTo(latLng);
        return marker;
        //markers.push(marker);
    }

    function addMarker(location, map, elevator)
    {   var marker = placeMarkerAndPanTo(location, map);
        var elevation = getElevation(location, elevator);

        markers.push({marker, elevation});
    }
```

Comment: You **are** using an asynchronous function. This is why the `getElevationForLocations` has a callback function. So you should do it the other way around: call the service, and in the callback function, create your marker and push it to the array with the elevation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of your code, using what I described in my comment.

```js
var markers = [];
var elevator = new google.maps.ElevationService;
var map;

function initMap() {

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {
      lat: -25.363882,
      lng: 131.044922
    },
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });

  map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    addMarker(e.latLng);
  });
}

function addMarker(location) {

  elevator.getElevationForLocations({
    'locations': [location]
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {

      // Retrieve the first result
      if (results[0]) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: location,
          map: map
        });

        map.panTo(location);

        markers.push({
          marker: marker,
          elevation: results[0].elevation
        });

        console.log(markers);
      }
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
#map {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

**Edit:** Seems there is a problem loading the API from the snippet at the moment (at least for me, it is crashing my browser), so here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/jhbkbxpw/) as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot ^^ It was so simple and I already knew this method but I just couldn't remember it ^^'